# How would I decode this array of digits to characters

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm attempting to create a plugin for a game that does not have any official support for user-created content. The goal is to decode a file that is used to transfer content from one server to another, so that I can edit it.

The data in this cluster file that I am trying to alter is encoded and stored in an array of numbers. I am able to decode some of it by using String.fromCharCode(), but it still is not completely human readable enough to be accurately altered.

The below block is what I am currently attempting to use to decode the array. I have limited it to numbers between 1 & 127 because some characters are not being recognized & making it difficult to paste into this post.

```
    let text = '';
    mysteryNumbers.forEach(code => {
        if (code >= 1 && code <= 127) {
            text += String.fromCharCode(code);
        }else{
            text += code;
        }
    });
    console.log(text);
```

Note: I'm including about 10% of the array to keep the size manageable for this post. The first block is the Array of integers I want to decode. The second block is an attempt at decoding the integers to their intended character using the above function.

```
[62, -108, 18, 72, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -94, -75, 66, 71, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -103, 123, 58, 69, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, -64, -58, 68, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 123, -4, 75, 70, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -56, 66, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -92, 65, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, -106, -48, 64, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, -102, -103, -23, 63, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 67, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 83, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 86, 97, 108, 117, 101, 115, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 70, 108, 111, 97, 116, 80, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 121, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 78, 111, 110, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 78, 111, 110, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

```
>-108H000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty00000000-94-75BG000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty0000000-103{:E000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty00000000000000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty00000000-64-58D000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty0000000{-4KF000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty000000000-56B000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty00000000000000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty000000000-92A000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty0000000-106-48@000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty0000    000-102-103-23?000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty0000
0000000000CurrentStatusValues0000FloatProperty00000000000000None00000000None00000
```

Comment: What's your specific need/question here? That the "decoded" string is still hard to read? That's because the developers of that game have come up with a proprietary data format that only they know how to parse/compose. If you want to reverse engineer it, you just have to look at it long and hard, and edit it, and save it and see what happens, and essentially figure it out by trial and error.

Comment: The specific need is to determine if there is an explanation of why most of the characters will "decode" to readable English, but not all of it. It does not make sense that this would produce readable results if they were using a proprietary data structure. Instead, it seems to me like I have done something wrong or overlooked a step. I can accept coincidence as the answer to this specific question, but I am ignorant in this area and will not be able to come to that conclusion on my own.